# What am I doing wrong in my windows batch script, I'm trying to understand the logic behind script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

So here is a bat script that is working, it is removing letter P from every jpg files that start with letter P in a folder.

```
@echo off
  for %%a in (p*.*) do ren "p*" "/*"
```

I want to understand the logic behind this script, so I'm messing around with it.

If I want remove letter P at end of files, I changed it but it didn't work,

What exactly am I doing wrong?

All I need to move P from beginning to end in the %%a and after ren command.

```
@echo off
      for %%a in (*.*P) do ren "*P" "/*"
```

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information for the command your are having an issue with.

Comment: The special `ren` quirk using `/` in the new name only removes leading characters, so when you want to remove the last character(s) you need to do that on your own; take a look at [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)…

Comment: @aschipfl can you give me more info, I'm running that as bat script in notepad.

Comment: What is the point of using a `FOR` command if you are not going to use the file names it is iterating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that you specifically want to rename the file starting with `p` and have a `.jpg` extension. Meaning you want to move the starting `p` to the end of the name, before the extension. This example does exactly that:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansiob
Pushd "D:\location of files here"
for %%i in (p*.jpg) do (
    set "name=%%~ni"
    ren "!name:~1!!name:~0,1!%%~xi"
)
Popd
```

Short explanation. We do for `p*.jpg` to ensure we only iterate through files starting with p and have a `jpg` extension.

We set the variable `%name%` to the name only of the file `%%~ni` (also seen as `!name!` because we have enabled `delayedexpansion`)

We then use variable expansion to strip parts of the name. Here we say print everything in the variable `!name!` excluding the first character as `!name:~1!`

Then use only the first character as starting from character zero, selecting only one. `!name:~0,1!` and simply give it back the extension `%%~xi`

To read more on the help of everything we have used here, open `cmd` and type the following:

```
for /?
set /?
setlocal /?
```

Everything we mentioned in this answer, is available in the help of the above.

Comment: it didn't work? Should I put the location of images for setlocal part